# Speeding up Haskell PBKDF2 algorithm

Tags: performance, haskell, pbkdf2

I have written a new version of the PBKDF2 algorithm in Haskell. It passes almost all of the HMAC-SHA-1 test vectors listed in [RFC 6070](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt), but it is not very efficient. How can I improve the code?

When I run it on the test vectors, the third case (see below) never finishes (I left it running for more than 1/2 hour on a 2010 Macbook Pro).

I believe that the `foldl'` is my problem. Will `foldr` perform better, or do I need to use mutable arrays?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{- Copyright 2013, G. Ralph Kuntz, MD. All rights reserved. LGPL License. -}

module Crypto where

import Codec.Utils (Octet)
import qualified Data.Binary as B (encode)
import Data.Bits (xor)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C (pack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L (unpack)
import Data.List (foldl')
import Data.HMAC (hmac_sha1)
import Text.Bytedump (dumpRaw)

-- Calculate the PBKDF2 as a hexadecimal string
pbkdf2
  :: ([Octet] -> [Octet] -> [Octet])  -- pseudo random function (HMAC)
  -> Int  -- hash length in bytes
  -> String  -- password
  -> String  -- salt
  -> Int  -- iterations
  -> Int  -- derived key length in bytes
  -> String
pbkdf2 prf hashLength password salt iterations keyLength =
  let
    passwordOctets = stringToOctets password
    saltOctets = stringToOctets salt
    totalBlocks =
      ceiling $ (fromIntegral keyLength :: Double) / fromIntegral hashLength
    blockIterator message acc =
      foldl' (\(a, m) _ ->
        let !m' = prf passwordOctets m
        in (zipWith xor a m', m')) (acc, message) [1..iterations]
  in
    dumpRaw $ take keyLength $ foldl' (\acc block ->
      acc ++ fst (blockIterator (saltOctets ++ intToOctets block)
                      (replicate hashLength 0))) [] [1..totalBlocks]
  where
    intToOctets :: Int -> [Octet]
    intToOctets i =
      let a = L.unpack . B.encode $ i
      in drop (length a - 4) a

    stringToOctets :: String -> [Octet]
    stringToOctets = L.unpack . C.pack

-- Calculate the PBKDF2 as a hexadecimal string using HMAC and SHA-1
pbkdf2HmacSha1
  :: String  -- password
  -> String  -- salt
  -> Int  -- iterations
  -> Int  -- derived key length in bytes
  -> String
pbkdf2HmacSha1 =
  pbkdf2 hmac_sha1 20
```

### Third test vector

```
 Input:
   P = "password" (8 octets)
   S = "salt" (4 octets)
   c = 16777216
   dkLen = 20

 Output:
   DK = ee fe 3d 61 cd 4d a4 e4
        e9 94 5b 3d 6b a2 15 8c
        26 34 e9 84             (20 octets)
```

Comment: A quick observation: you're not really forcing `m` in your `foldl'` argument. As `m` is a list you need to use e.g. `deepSeq` to force all of it.

Comment: Possible I'm dead wrong on this as I'm not a real strong Haskeller, but the amount you have crammed into one function makes it a bit hard to penetrate, if you break it up across smaller simpler pieces you may find spaces for improvement become very obvious.

Comment: I'd highly recommend changing the algorithm to work over `ByteString`s  (which can be somewhat easily treated as vectors of `Word8`s) rather than lists of `Octet`s. I can't imagine it's the only reason for the slowness, though this is also a somewhat tricky algorithm to test since you can tune it to take however long you like.

Comment: I'm going to take a look at using `ByteString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it to complete in ~16 min on my MacBookPro:

```
% time Crypto-Main
eefe3d61cd4da4e4e9945b3d6ba2158c2634e984                          
./Crypto-Main  1027.30s user 15.34s system 100% cpu 17:22.61 total
```

by changing the strictness of your fold:

```
let
  -- ...
  blockIterator message acc = foldl' (zipWith' xor) acc ms
    where ms = take iterations . tail $ iterate (prf passwordOctets) message
          zipWith' f as bs = let cs = zipWith f as bs in sum cs `seq` cs
in
  dumpRaw $ take keyLength $ foldl' (\acc block ->
    acc ++ blockIterator (saltOctets ++ intToOctets block)
                    (replicate hashLength 0)) [] [1..totalBlocks]
```

Note how I force the full evaluation of each `zipWith xor`. In order to calculate
`sum cs` into WHNF, we must know the exact value of each element in `cs`.

This prevents building up a chain of thunks, which I think your existing code was attempting to do, but failing, as `foldl'` only forces the accumulator into WHNF. Since your accumulator was a pair, the WHNF is just `(_thunk, _another_thunk)`, so your intermediate thunks were not getting forced.

Comment: You have more patience than I do. I waited about 30 minutes with the original version, but it did not complete. I'll take a look at your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: On http://codereview.stackexchange.com, Petr Pudlák suggested that the better solution might use unboxed ST arrays. I'll have to look at that.

Comment: I actually rewrote the function using unboxed ST arrays, but it is still quite slow. I'll need to run performance testing to find out why.